# How to display a dynamic date in a display ad

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I would like to create a display ad where the date in the ad changes each day to: todays date +14 weeks

As it is a HTML5 ad then I assume the best (and only?) way to achieve this is through javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Days=14
let result = new Date();
result.setDate(result.getDate() + Days);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want 98 days in the future:

```js
function daysInFuture(days, func, continuous = true){
  requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
    func(new Date(Date.now()+86400000*days));
    if(continuous)daysInFuture(days, func, continuous);
  }); 
}
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
const out = document.getElementById('out');
daysInFuture(98, factored=>{
  out.textContent = factored.toString();
}/*, false (if you want to not be continuous) */);
}); // end load
```

```html
<div id='out'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks - how does one control the output (currently shows, day, month, date, year, time, timezone etc) How do just show the day, date and month?

Comment: `factored` has all the properties of [Date.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 0):

OK, below is my answer (pretty new to this and I realised my question was awful in many ways and didn't show research etc) Thanks to those who tried to help but I figured out what I wanted to do and here is how:

**What question should have been:** Using javascript, how do I display a date 98 days in the future and how can I display parts of the date separately and also display the name of the month.

**Answer:**

```
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";

var d = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 98;
d.setDate(d.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 

var n = month[d.getMonth()];
document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = n;
document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = d.getDate();

<p id="month"></p>
<p id="day"></p>
```